# Matching the large digit on monitor display with szDevice in MONITORINFOEX

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm implementing an application which Screen captures selected monitor by User. UI is designed exactly same as "Monitor Display".

[image]

I've been searching how to get the large digit and I figured out that is not supported officially but I found some possibility when I tested **EnumDisplayMonitors**.

Enumertaion callback gives *szDevice* which is in **MONITORINFOEX**  and this is matched with "Monitor Display" 's. ie) **szDevice** : **.//./DISPLAY1** matched **large digit "1"**.

I've tested couple of machine and always same result. Can I assume that this digit end of **szDevice** is always same as "Monitor Display" 's? Any help will be appriciated. Thanks.

Comment: What does the large digit mean?

Comment: Surely the exact value of the digit does not matter at all.  Nor ought to be there a compelling reason in your case to display the digit on the actual monitor like the Display applet does when you use "identify monitor".  Regardless, using color to indicate the selected monitor is fine as well.  That nail can be struck by many kinds of hammers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to be trying to replicate the display used to arrange the monitors in the control panel screen resolution applet which uses a large number to identify the displays. This appears to simply be the order in which these monitors are enumerated as the digit appended to the szDevice field of the `MONITORINFOEX` structure returned by `GetMonitorInfo()` uses different numbers.

On my laptop with 2 monitors attached we get a UI display as shown below. [image: three monitor arrangement]

Note that the primary monitor is in the middle and has a number 3. The top-left of this monitor will be 0,0.

The program below shows that `EnumDisplayMonitors` returns these monitors in the same numerical sequence (1, 2, 3):

```
C:\Code\Demos>lsmonitor.exe
1 00010003 -1920x0+0+1080\\.\DISPLAY1
2 00010005 1920x0+3840+1080\\.\DISPLAY2
3 00010001 0x0+1920+1080\\.\DISPLAY4 (primary)
```

Test program (in C). We have to track the display index ourselves (in this case the `counter` variable in the main function:

```
/* Print out information about the connected monitors
 *
 * To compile:
 *  (MSVC++):  cl -nologo -W3 -MDd -Zi -Od lsmonitor.c
 */

#define UNICODE
#define _UNICODE
#define WIN32
#define STRICT
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "user32")

static void PrintError(LPCTSTR szPrefix, DWORD dwError);

static BOOL CALLBACK
MonitorEnumProc(HMONITOR hMonitor, HDC hdcMonitor, LPRECT prcMonitor, LPARAM pData)
{
    int *pCounter = (int *)pData;
    MONITORINFOEX mi;
    mi.cbSize = sizeof(mi);

    *pCounter += 1;

    _tprintf(_T("%d %p %dx%d+%d+%d"),
             *pCounter,
             hMonitor,
             prcMonitor->left, prcMonitor->top,
             prcMonitor->right, prcMonitor->bottom);
    if (GetMonitorInfo(hMonitor, (LPMONITORINFO)&mi))
    {
        _tprintf(_T("%.*s"), CCHDEVICENAME, mi.szDevice);
        if (mi.dwFlags == MONITORINFOF_PRIMARY)
            _tprintf(_T(" (primary)"));
    }
    else
    {
        PrintError(_T("GetMonitorInfo"), GetLastError());
    }

    _puttchar('\n');
    return TRUE;
}

int
_tmain(int argc, TCHAR *argv)
{
    HDC hdc = NULL; /* NULL means all screens */
    LPRECT prcClip = NULL; /* No clipping */
    int counter = 0;
    BOOL br = EnumDisplayMonitors(hdc, prcClip, MonitorEnumProc, (LPARAM)&counter);
    if (!br)
    {
        PrintError(_T("EnumDisplayMonitors"), GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }
}

static void
PrintError(LPCTSTR szPrefix, DWORD dwError)
{
    LPTSTR lpsz = NULL;
    DWORD cch = 0;

    cch = FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER
                        | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM
                        | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
                        NULL, dwError, LANG_NEUTRAL,
                        (LPTSTR)&lpsz, 0, NULL);
    if (cch < 1) {
        cch = FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER
                            | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_STRING
                            | FORMAT_MESSAGE_ARGUMENT_ARRAY,
                            "Code 0x%1!08x!",
                            0, LANG_NEUTRAL, (LPTSTR)&lpsz, 0,
                            (va_list*)&dwError);
    }

    _ftprintf(stderr, _T("%s (0x%08x): %s"), szPrefix, dwError, lpsz);

    LocalFree((HLOCAL)lpsz);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I doubt enumeration sequence is always guaranteed, is it?

Comment: MSDN doesn't document the ordering so there are no guarantees but I suspect it will be constant until the hardware changes. The display cards will be enumerated is some order (I have 2, intel and nvidia here) then for each card the attached monitors must be enumerated. My 1 and 2 are on one card then the primary (3) is on the second display card. For a guarantee you'd need to match the device names and use those to index any numbering system you choose to use.